# How to get last value from mysql record

Tags: php, mysql

i'm php beginner please help me..

i have mysql record like bellow

```
id   name     value_1   value_2
 1   rakesh   100      50
 2   david    150      10
 3   richard   0       0
 4   michael   0       0
```

I want last record value_1 to do some math 
But if last record value_1==0 means i want to go and get upper top value_1 (value_1=150)

i use bellow code but i get only last value

```
$get=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name ");
$got = mysql_fetch_array($get);
$next_id = $got['MAX(id)'];
```

here  get 3d richard value_1==0 
but i want 2nd david value_1 150

please help me thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the desired output for the sample data you posted?

Comment: Keep the last row that has a positive value in a variable, say $last_positive. Whenever you get to a row with 0, just use the value from that stored in $last_positive.

Comment: what do you really want to get? the `ID` or `Value_1`?

Answer (score 5):

Your query is giving you the last row, because you are always selecting the biggest id.

Try with that:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value_1 > 0 ORDER BY value_1 DESC LIMIT 1
```

- It will select the whole row so you won't need to make an additional query.
- `WHERE value_1` > 0 will select only rows where `value_1` is bigger than 0. It assumes that such records exists though. Let me know if this is not your case.
- `ORDER BY value_1 DESC` tells the query to order the rows by `value_1` in descending order and thus the desired row will be on top.
- `LIMIT 1` selects the first row only.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name WHERE value_1 <> 0
```

Will select the maximum ID where `value_1` is not 0

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$get=mysql_query("SELECT value_1 FROM table_name 
                  WHERE  value_1 != 0 
                  ORDER BY id DESC 
                  LIMIT 1");
```

I actually didn't understood the question, Here is another answer wich give you different result :

```
$get=mysql_query("SELECT value_1 FROM table_name 
                  WHERE  value_1 != 0 
                  ORDER BY value_1 DESC 
                  LIMIT 1");
```

Diff with both the queries is that one is `ORDER BY id DESC` and other is `ORDER BY value_1 DESC`

Comment: he wants to get the `ID` not the value, *I guess*

Comment: @JW : Question is little confusing he says : "here get 3d richard value_1==0 but i want 2nd david value_1 150"